# Error haciendo UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Actualizacion completada.</title> 
</head> 
<body> 

<?php 

$docu = $_POST['docu']; 
$apat = $_POST['apat']; 
$amat = $_POST['amat']; 
$nomb = $_POST['nomb']; 
$corr = $_POST['corr']; 

echo "$docu";
// Actualizamos en funcion del id que recibimos
$base = "hcc";  
$tabla = "members";
$user = "xxxx";
$pasw = "yy" ; 

$enlace =  mysql_connect('localhost',$user,$pasw);
echo mysql_errno($enlace) . ": " . mysql_error($enlace). "\n";
echo "<br>"; 

$bdatabase = mysql_select_db('hcc', $enlace);
echo mysql_errno($enlace) . ": " . mysql_error($enlace). "\n";
echo "<br>" 

//mysql_query("UPDATE 'members' SET 'a_pat'='$apat' ", $enlace) or die (mysql_error()); 
$ssql = "UPDATE $tabla SET a_pat='$apat' WHERE doc='$docu' ";
$resultUpdat = mysql_query($sql); 
//$resultUpdate = mysqli_query($enlace, $ssql); 
 if($resultUpdate)
         {
            echo "<strong>El actualizo el registro ID ".$_POST['docu']." con exito</strong>. <br>";
         }
         else
         {
            echo "No se pudo actualizar el registro. <br>";
         }
//mysql_query($queryUpdate); 

mysql_close($enlace); 

echo " 

"; 

?> 

<p>Los datos han sido actualizados con exito.</p> 

<p><a href='edicion.html'>RETORNO INICIO</a></p> 
</body> 

</html>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: deberias explicar cual es el error que te esta dando...

Comment: Tu codigo presenta errores graves de seguridad Mysql esta obsoleto y ya ha dejado de considerarse seguro, en ves de eso deberias usar mysqli o pdo

Comment: Admas respondiendo a tu error en tu primer mysql_query tienes unas comillas simples que no deberian estar al momento de selecionar la tabla y el campo dentro de la tabla

Comment: Al parecer has **involucionado** en tu código: `$resultUpdat = mysql_query($sql); 
//$resultUpdate = mysqli_query($enlace, $ssql); ` me refiero a que **tienes comentada la función que en realidad deberías usar, cambiándola por una función obsoleta**. Como ya comentó @Risa__B, se recomienda usar MySQLi o PDO, porque la extensión `mysql_*` es obsoleta. Por otra parte hay una condición que nunca se cumplirá: `if($resultUpdate) ...`  debido a que cuando involucionaste, cometiste un error ortográfico, llamado a la variable:  `$resultUpdat`

Comment: Gracias, muchas gracias a todos. Lo que veo es que muchos programitas armados con extractos de internet estan tambien usando versiones antiguas. Gracias Gbianchi,Risa_B, Acedano. Restructurare nuevamente todo. :)

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que el error que te estará dando se debe a que estás utilizando por un lado "mysql_connect" para realizar la cadena de conexión y después "mysqli" para realizar el procesado de las consultas. Estos dos métodos no son compatibles.
Si quieres que todo te funcione deberías cambiar a utilizar "mysql" para realizar todo el proceso o "mysqli" para lo mismo.

Te dejo aquí el código para que realices todo con "mysqli"

```
//Cadena de conexión
$con=mysqli_connect($hos_name, $user_name, $password, $database);

//Procesado de la consulta
$consulta="SELECT * FROM TABLA";
$resultado=$con->query($consulta);
$fila=$resultado->fetch_array();
```